# Can a Professor move a class an hour earlier?

Tags: professorship

My professor moved class from 1:30 to 12:30 and I missed class and a big research presentation i was supposed to give.  Is he allowed to move class like that?

Comment: One would assume that the instructor asked the students in the course if that was OK, and he didn't hear otherwise. So, you should clarify if that is the case or not.

Comment: If the university allows them, yes. We cannot really say anything more.

Comment: When did he announce the move?

Comment: This would be very unusual in the U.S.  At the very least I would expect him to notify everyone by email.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your University's policies. At my University, professors are not allowed (see [1]:34-83). Your University might have some stipulations regarding this (e.g. was it done with due notice? what happens to students who were absent the day it was decided?).

Your best choice would be to check the policies and see if you have the right to give your presentation during office hours or at another time.

References:
[1] http://senate.psu.edu/policies-and-rules-for-undergraduate-students/34-00-course-scheduling/#34-83